# avoid code duplication on multiple c++ template spezialization

Tags: c++, templates, code-duplication

I looked around for a good solution to avoid code duplication on each spezialization of a template class.

Here is an example code:

```
template<class T>
class C
{
    int foo();
}
```

Now the definition for defaults:

```
template<class T>
C<T>::foo() { return 0; }
```

Now the spezailization for special templates

```
template<> C<int>::foo()    { ... do a lot of stuff and return n .... }
template<> C<double>::foo() { ... do a lot of stuff and return n .... }
template<> C<int>::foo()    { ... do a lot of stuff and return n .... }
```

Right now I have to duplicate the code for the spezailization. But in general it's the same code.

My questions is:
What is the best solution to avoid code duplication here and how can I hide the implementation ? Maybe by using a noname-namespace or an impl-namespace ?

Kind regards,
Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as with any other class: extract the boilerplate code to another (private) function in the template class and call this one in your specializations.

```
template<class T>
class C
{
    int foo();

    void bar() { /* does lot of stuff ... */ }
};

template<> int C<int>::foo() { bar(); return n .... }
template<> int C<double>::foo() { bar(); return n .... }
```

> and how can I hide the implementation ? Maybe by using a noname-namespace or an impl-namespace ?

It's not really possible to hide the implementation of template code, by means of having a compilation unit specific unnamed namespace.

If your intend mainly is to get a cleaner readable template header file, you can factor out the implementation to another included file. These are often named `.tcc` or `.icc`, there are samples for this technique in most of the c++ implementation standard header files.

Comment: Would it be also possible to hide bar() inside a unnamed namespace inside a header file ?

Comment: @Peter Unfortunately not for templates. Anonymous (unnamed) namespaces relate and are private to the compilation unit they are placed in. Since a template class doesn't have a (primary) compilation unit, I'm afraid that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

One way to avoid duplicating code is to use a base class to handle generic implementation:

```
template <class T>
class base_C
{
    void generic_foo(){...}
};

template <>
class C <SpecialType> : base_C<SpecialType>
{
    void foo()
    {
        SpecialType::custom_foo();
        base_C<SpecialType>::generic_foo();
    }
};
```

The idea begind this is to split `foo` into more generic parts and put them into `base_C`. With this each specialization of `C::foo` will have a minimal amount of custom code.